# select top 3 unique items in a list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have a list of items and it outputs a list of list:

```
item_list = ['book', 'pen']
output = [
    ['pencil', 'eraser', 'pen', 'glue', 'folders'], 
    ['notepad', 'book','pencil', 'markers','ruler','scissors']
]
```

Is there a way to get the output as a unique list of items that contains the top 3 items from each sublist but also not in the initial `item_list`?

so that the output will look like (in the exact order):

```
new_output = ['pencil', 'eraser', 'glue', 'notepad', 'markers', 'ruler']
```

or if possible:

```
new_output = ['pencil', 'notepad', 'eraser', 'markers', 'glue','ruler']
```

Comment: how do you decide which item is top?

Comment: It was originally a dataframe with item and value columns but I had it sorted and only took the item column and put it as list.

Comment: I'm not asking from where you getting the list, what i'm asking is how do you find top 3 items?

Comment: When you say "top 3 items", what does that *mean*? For example, what is the rule that tells you that `'pencil'`, `'eraser'` and `'glue'` are the "top 3 items" in the first list, and `'folders'` is not one of them?

Comment: Also: what should you do if there are not 3 usable items in a given input list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must keep a `set` of already seen items to find the unique ones. A trivial implementation would be:

```
item_list = ['book', 'pen']
output = [['pencil', 'eraser', 'pen', 'glue', 'folders'],
          ['notepad', 'book', 'pencil', 'markers', 'ruler', 'scissors']]

already_seen = set(item_list)
new_output = []
for sublist in output:
  new_sublist = [item for item in sublist if item not in already_seen]
  new_output.extend(new_sublist[:3])
  already_seen |= set(new_sublist[:3])

print(new_output)
```

output:

```
['pencil', 'eraser', 'glue', 'notepad', 'markers', 'ruler']
```

Comment: what does ```already_seen |= set(new_sublist)``` do between the sets?

Comment: If you turn the comprehension into a generator and call `next` on it three times (e.g. with `itertools.isloce`), you can avoid the need to turn the whole row into a list. Not as pretty, but more efficient.

Comment: @fardinho21. Adding to a set. Logical or is a union operation.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Good idea but I will leave the answer as it is not to further complicate it.

Comment: @Chs In that case you should change the relevant line to `already_seen |= set(new_sublist[:3])`. See updated answer.

Comment: @Selcuk thank you so much for the quick answer! It really helped me a lot! And again sorry for being vague and wording it weirdly :)